# Run command inside command on CMDER windows

Tags: linux, docker, cmder

I have docker and i want to remove all running container with this command on `Cmder` app for Windows
But i got an error. How to run equivalent command on windows cmd ?

```
$ docker container rm -f $(docker container ls -aq)
```

Error response :

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -aq)
See 'docker container rm --help'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use first docker images which brings you all the current images.

```
docker images
```

Then you can use this command;

```
docker rmi -f 'firstImageId' 'secondImageId'
```

Details can be found on the link;https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/

Comment: If use this command i must specify the image or container id one by one, but if i use this `$ docker container rm -f $(docker container ls -aq)` i can remove it all automatically because `docker container ls -aq` will display all container id in list but this command only can run on linux terminal. My question is how to make this command equivalent on windows cmd